# I have tried TimeValue() and tried working with excels fractions to indicate a time and I tried the Hours Minutes functions and combinations of these

Tags: vba

I am having trouble getting a VBA code to compare the date and time of the following:

```
2012/05/01 00:00:00
2012/05/01 00:03:00
2012/05/01 00:06:00
2012/05/01 00:15:00
2012/05/01 00:18:00
```

to give me the answer below

```
2012/05/01 00:00:00
2012/05/01 00:03:00
2012/05/01 00:06:00
2012/05/01 00:09:00
2012/05/01 00:12:00
2012/05/01 00:15:00
2012/05/01 00:18:00
```

The problem is that if I compare current date and time value with the next date and time value excel sometimes thinks the data and time is not the same even though in VBA watch the values are the same. I have to do this check on a whole month with a 3 minute interval between each time stamp. There are data entries next to these time stamps. I am able to create just the time stamps starting at the 2012/05/01 00:00:00 and ending at the end of the month but I need it to fill in missing entries in the data set. The code below works but only some of the time as mentioned above. I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to works.

Thank you for any help

```
    Sub Insert_missing_3min()
```

'Inserts a row with the date and time where the missing date and time stamp is and a zero next to the date added.

```
Dim min3 As Date
Dim CurTime As Date
Dim CurCell As Date
Dim NextCell As Date

min3 = 3 / 24 / 60

If (Hour(ActiveCell) <> 0 Or Minute(ActiveCell) <> 0 Or Day(ActiveCell) <> 1) Then      'makes the start date the fisrt of the month at 00:00
  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
  ActiveCell.Value = Year(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) & "/" & Month(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) & "/" & "1"

End If

Maand = Month(ActiveCell)

Do While IsDate(ActiveCell) And Month(ActiveCell) = Maand

        NextCell = DateAdd("n", TimeValue(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))


        If (NextCell <> DateAdd("n", 3, ActiveCell) And NextCell > DateAdd("n", 3, ActiveCell)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = DateAdd("n", 3, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0))   '3 min time value in excell
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0                     ' Value in colum next to date 0
            With Selection.Interior                                 ' Highlight
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: I am sorry if this seems like a dumb question but I can't seem to get it right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `dateadd` function to manipulate dates.

So wherever you have `date + min3` change it to `DateAdd("n", 3, date)`

Comment: I found something else, it always makes a mistake if the last number in minutes is a four or a nine.